# Change ::before background-image with variable in Astro

Tags: html, css, background-image, astrojs

I am creating an unordered list (ul) where, upon hovering over an list item (li), the **::before** pseudo-element positioned to the left of the li changes its background-image.

I need to call a component that contains an li (I'm using Astro) and pass a prop with the ImageMetadata. However, I don't know how to insert the image in the ::before background-image when the user hovers hover the li.

I need to make it callable.

Calling the component:

```
  <Book index='5' title='Proyects' img={proyectsImg}></Book>
```

Component:

```html
<li id="item" style=`--i:${index}; --urlimg:'${urlImg}';`>
  <a href="#" class="flex justify-between flex-col align h-full items-center" ><span id="title">{title}</span><span id="sign">?</span></a>
</li>
```

I tried to do it inside the  of the astro component but i dont now how to concatenate the image on the background-image.
Also i tried do it using  in the astro component but i dont know how to refeer the ::before background-image

Answer (score 0):

In your `<Book>` component, you can use the passed `ImageMetadata`’s `src` property to create a CSS variable the `::before` pseudo element styles can reference.

One thing to note: you must use the CSS `url()` function inside your custom property (`--urlimg`).

Here’s what the markup would look like:

```
---
const { img, index } = Astro.props;
---

<li style={`--i: ${index}; --urlimg: url('${img.src}');`}>
  <a>...</a>
</li>
```

Then in your CSS, you can use the variable:

```css
li:hover::before {
  background-image: var(--urlimg);
}
```

Or, if you’re using Tailwind like it looks like based on your `<a>` class names:

```html
<li class="hover:before:bg-[var(--urlimg)]">
```

---

Note that this uses the original image passed to the component. If you needed to resize or optimize it, you could use Astro’s `getImage()` helper to do that:

```
---
import { getImage } from "astro:assets";

const { img, index } = Astro.props;
const optimizedImage = await getImage({ src: img, width: 500 });
---

<li style={`--i: ${index}; --urlimg: url('${optimizedImage.src}');`}>
```